# Split string by adresses in Python like in C (Python's String Slicing)

Tags: python, c, python-2.7, pointers, slice

In C you can access where you want in the string with adress of the char by doing that:

```
&string[index]
```

For exmple this code :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  char *foo = "abcdefgh";
  printf("%s\n", &foo[2]);
}
```

Will return:

```
cdefgh
```

Is there a way to do that in Python ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Python it is known as *string slicing* and the syntax is:

```
>>> foo = "abcdefgh"
>>> foo[2:]
'cdefgh'
```

Check [Python's String Document](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#strings) which demonstrates the slicing feature along with other functions available with *strings* in python.

I will also suggest to take a look at: [Cutting and slicing strings in Python](http://pythoncentral.io/cutting-and-slicing-strings-in-python/) where it is demonstrated with some very nice examples.

Here are few examples related to slicing of string:

```
>>> foo[2:]     # start from 2nd index till end
'cdefgh'
>>> foo[:3]     # from start to 3rd index (excluding 3rd index)
'abc'
>>> foo[2:4]    # start from 2nd index till 4th index (excluding 4th index)
'cd'
>>> foo[2:-1]   # start for 2nd index excluding last index
'cdefg'
>>> foo[-3:-1]  # from 3rd last index to last index ( excluding last index)
'fg'
>>> foo[1:6:2]  # from 1st to 6th index (excluding 6th index) with jump/step of "2"
'bdf'
>>> foo[::-1]   # reverse the string; my favorite ;)
'hgfedcba'
```

Answer (score 2):

This is how you can do it:

```
foo = "abcdefgh"
print foo[2:]
```

More generally; `foo[a:b]` means characters from position `a` (included) to `b` (excluded).

Answer (score 1):

For you problem "slicing" is the answer.

syntax : `s[a:b]`

this will give you a string from index a to b-1
If you want string starting from a index till end then use

`s[a:]`

and if you want string from starting till index b then use

`s[:b+1]`

And for your example :

```
s="abcdefgh"
print s[2:]
```

will print `cdefgh` and hence is the answer to your problem.

You could read more about it from https://www.dotnetperls.com/substring-python

Comment: This answer is not wrong, but it can be improved.  Can you give the asker more information, so they can learn better?  What is it called when you use [:]?  Can you point them to a reference that explains how to use it, and summarize that reference in your answer?